# VBA Copying and pasting according to a search range (time)

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

I am super new to VBA, but I'm basically trying to use it to copy and paste whatever is in J23:L23 into a cell that I am searching for. The data that I am searching for is a particular time in Column C (not sure if that makes a difference). Also the timevalues in column C and that I'm searching for is not simply the time, but also includes date data but on my excel sheet, the cells are in time format. I really have no idea why my code is not working, but it'll be great if someone could help me!

This is what i have written so far

```
Sub Scheduling_Appts()
    Dim appt As Range
    Set appt = Range("C12:C1195").Find(what:=Range("N23").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Range("J23:L23").Copy Range("appt").Offset(, 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing of `what:=Range("N23").Value` with  `what:=CDbl(Range("N23").Value)`

Comment: i tried changing it to CDbl, but it still doesn't work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Replace that last line with `If Not appt is Nothing Then`, `Range("J23:L23").Copy appt.Offset(,2)`, `End If`.

Comment: @BigBen when I replace the last line with what you wrote it says "Expected: line number or label or statement or end of statement"

Comment: What BigBen suggested must be written on three lines. Without comma, of course...

Comment: it runs now but nothing is being copy and pasted

Comment: Try inserting of `Debug.Print appt.Adress` before `If Not appt is Nothing Then`. And see if it returns something in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G in VBE)

Comment: oh thanks guys i figured it out. I changed everything in column c and the n23 cell to numbers and then changed it back to time after i ran the stuff above^. Thanks nonetheless you lovely people